# Something goes wrong when adding jedi-vim

Tags: python, vim, git-submodules, git-clone, jedi-vim

I followed mbrochh's instruction https://github.com/mbrochh/vim-as-a-python-ide to build my vim as a python IDE. But things go wrong when openning the vim after I put `jedi-vim` into `~/.vim/bundle`. The following is the warnings

```
Error detected while processing CursorMovedI Auto commands for "buffer=1":
Traceback (most recent call last)

Error detected while processing CursorMovedI Auto commands for "buffer=1":
  File "string", line 1, in module

Error detected while processing CursorMovedI Auto commands for "buffer=1":
NameError: name 'jedi_vim' is not defined
```

I hope someone can figure out the problem and thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry for the impropriety.It's my first time asking question here,so I don't know some rules.

Comment: @IngoKarkat, this is not Jedi-vim issue. This is wrong git usage problem. I'm sure that stackoverflow is the place where you can receive an appropriate answer for your technical question. If we are community of stackoverflow we should figure out the meaning of question and provide a useful answer. But not indiscriminately chase inquirers, especially if the inquirer is new to stackowerflow.

Answer (score 3):

If you’re trying to use Vundle to install the jedi-vim plugin, I don’t think you should have to place it under `~/.vim/bundle`. Instead, make sure you have Vundle set up correctly, as [described in its “Quick start”](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle#quick-start), and then try adding this line to your `~/.vimrc` after the lines where Vundle is set up:

```
Plugin 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'
```

Then run `:PluginInstall` and the plugin should be installed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I will try the way you said. I have used pathogen following the instruction. And The problem is fixed when I use git submodule update to install jedi instead of pip.

Comment: with Vundle, wouldn't it be `Plugin 'davidhalter/jedi-vim`?

Comment: Hi @drs! Yeah, it turns out that it would be… now. :) This answer was written a couple of months before `Bundle` was changed to `Plugin`. I updated it—thanks.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that you have install jedi,
I solved my problem with below command..

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim  
git submodule update --init
```

Answer (score 1):

(Using ubuntu 14.04LTS with Python 2.7)

I had a very similar issue and I found that I needed to integrate Jedi into my Python installation.

I did the following...

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip

sudo pip install jedi
```

Then if you haven't done so already, you can then add Jedi to VIM via Pathogen as follows...

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle

curl -so ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/master/autoload/pathogen.vim
```

Then... add this line to your '**~/.vimrc**' file (Create it if it doesn't already exist.)

```
call pathogen#infect()
```

Then Save and Quit.

Lastly...

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle

git clone git://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim.git
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies exists in the Jedi git repo. *I expect you are using pathogen as extension manager.* Use `git clone` with `--recursive` option.

> cd ~/.vim/bundle/ && git clone --recursive https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim.git

Dave Halter has this instruction in the [docs on github](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim#installation).

---

BTW, this is common behavior for all vim extensions with dependencies, such as flake8-vim. Furthermore if you just  cloned any repo, which has dependencies, not recursively, you can have very unexpected issues. So this question in a greater extent about [git recursive cloning](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) and [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).